# Delphi 7 - ShellExecute command not working in situations

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I have made a Game Launcher and I use this command:

```
 procedure TFMain.ImgBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
     begin
      ShellExecute(TForm(Owner).Handle, nil, 'starter.exe', '-lang rus', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
     end;
```

with '-lang rus' as a parameter. Everything works fine. The Game Launches and the language is in russian(if i put '-lang eng' it still works fine and the game is in english).

The **starter.exe** application is inside a folder named ''**bin**''. When i want to relocate the launcher outside this folder i use this command:

```
procedure TFMain.ImgBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
     begin
      ShellExecute(TForm(Owner).Handle, nil, 'bin\starter.exe', '-lang rus', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
     end;
```

But then the game isn't launching. Actually nothing happens.
What should i change?

Comment: You should use fully-qualified paths.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Try passing the executable's directory in the `lpDirectory` parameter to `ShellExecute`.

Comment: 1. `TForm(Owner).Handle` looks dubious at best. In any case it's not needed. Pass `0`. 2. Use `CreateProcess` to create processes. Use `ShellExecuteEx` when you need to get the shell to work out how to resolve a shell verb. 3. Always check for errors. I can't imagine why you neglected this. That said, `ShellExecute` doesn't report errors in a sane way and you should never use it. If you have to resolve shell verbs, use `ShellExecuteEx` which does have proper error reporting.

Comment: Did you try `starter.exe -lang rus` on a commandline to look for potential error messages?

Comment: I did not checked for errors, i'll check it out and report back.

Comment: @user3211668 You cannot reliably check for errors with `ShellExecute`. You can with `ShellExecuteEx` but even so, `CreateProcess` is the right function to call.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use full path to the application you are trying to start.

`ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)` will give you full path to your launcher exe.

**Solution 1:** using `ShellExecute`

```
procedure TFMain.ImgBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  ExecuteResult: integer;
  Path: string;
begin
  Path := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName));
  ExecuteResult := ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar(Path + 'bin\starter.exe'), '-lang rus', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  if ExecuteResult <= 32 then ShowMessage('Error: ' + IntToStr(ExecuteResult));
end;
```

You can find list of error codes at: [ShellExecute function documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Most common error codes:

- `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 0x2`
- `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND 0x3`

**Solution 2:** using `ShellExecuteEx`

```
var
  FileName, Parameters, Folder: string;
  sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
  Error: DWORD;
  OK: boolean;
begin
  Folder := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)) + 'bin\';
  FileName := Folder + 'starter.exe';
  Parameters := '-lang rus';
  ZeroMemory(@sei, SizeOf(sei));
  sei.cbSize := SizeOf(sei);
  sei.lpFile := PChar(FileName);
  sei.lpParameters := PChar(Parameters);
  sei.lpDirectory := PChar(Folder);
  sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  OK := ShellExecuteEx(@sei);
  if not OK then
    begin
      Error := GetLastError;
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + IntToStr(Error));
    end;
end;
```

[ShellExecuteEx documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Solution 3:** using `CreateProcess`

```
function ExecuteProcess(const FileName, Params: string; Folder: string; WaitUntilTerminated, WaitUntilIdle, RunMinimized: boolean;
  var ErrorCode: integer): boolean;
var
  CmdLine: string;
  WorkingDirP: pchar;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  Result := true;
  CmdLine := '"' + FileName + '" ' + Params;
  if Folder = '' then Folder := ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(FileName));
  ZeroMemory(@StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo));
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
  if RunMinimized then
    begin
      StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWMINIMIZED;
    end;
  if Folder <> '' then WorkingDirP := pchar(Folder)
  else WorkingDirP := nil;
  if not CreateProcess(nil, pchar(CmdLine), nil, nil, false, 0, nil, WorkingDirP, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
    begin
      Result := false;
      ErrorCode := GetLastError;
      exit;
    end;
  with ProcessInfo do
    begin
      CloseHandle(hThread);
      if WaitUntilIdle then WaitForInputIdle(hProcess, INFINITE);
      if WaitUntilTerminated then
        repeat
          Application.ProcessMessages;
        until MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, hProcess, false, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1;
      CloseHandle(hProcess);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName, Parameters, Folder: string;
  Error: integer;
  OK: boolean;
begin
  Folder := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)) + 'bin\';
  FileName := Folder + 'starter.exe';
  Parameters := '-lang rus';
  OK := ExecuteProcess(FileName, Parameters, Folder, false, false, false, Error);
  if not OK then
    begin
      Error := GetLastError;
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + IntToStr(Error));
    end;
end;
```

[CreateProcess documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually `PChar` is fine for all Delphi versions

Comment: `ExtractFilePath()` usually includes the trailing slash, so don't include a leading slash in the `'bin\starter'`. Better would be to use `IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(...))`, to account for the corner cases where `ExtractFilePath()` does not include a trailing slash.

Comment: You link to an irrelevant set of error codes. These do not apply to ShellExecute. This leads on to the fact that you should **never** call ShellExecute.

Comment: There's no point at all trying to persist with this. There's no point writing code that doesn't deal with errors. Stop advocating ShellExecute. Never ever call it. ShellExecuteEx is your guy. However, in this scenario it is CreateProcess that is needed.

Comment: I could not disagree more. It is always a mistake to call SE. SEE is always preferred. And here CP is the correct choice.

Comment: Thank you. I think that is an improvement. I'd personally use `Win32Check(ShellExecuteEx(...))` but that's me. However, I still maintain that it is wrong to use even `ShellExecuteEx` to create a new process. This forces you to initialize COM. And why have `SEE` do all that work before it calls `CreateProcess`. Best just to call `CreateProcess` directly. The one exception (so far as I know) to that is when you need to use the `runas` verb.

Comment: @David In this case initalizing COM is not necessary.

Comment: You hope! The documentation doesn't give you any proof that is so. So, CP wins for me. I'm sorry to go on. I think I've made my opinions clear. I think I'll stop making any more mess around your answer.

Comment: @David I added CreateProcess too. We can delete comments later.

Comment: Your CP code does something quite different. It waits for termination. Much better to skip that so that the variants are all the same.

Comment: I thought the 'evil' Application.ProcessMessages should be avoided at any cost!

Comment: @Ampere Application.ProcessMessages is evil because people use it everywhere to solve problems the wrong way... if you have to execute and wait for a process then you will have to use Application.ProcessMessages. Now you can avoid that by spawning another thread and wait there without blocking main thread. Of course, if you don't have to wait for process to finish at all you can completely avoid tat loop. Depends on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use fully-qualified (absolute) paths. For instance, if you know that the path is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Game\bin\starter.exe
```

you should pass that string. Of course, you should **never** hard-code such a string, since it may be different on different systems. If your application is a general application launcher, you get the path from the user. If your application launches your own company's games, you have to figure out a clever way to communicate paths.

It is not clear from your question, but if `bin\starter.exe` is relative to the path of your application, you can use

```
ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'bin\starter.exe'
```

By the way, you could have figured all this out by yourself by looking at the return value of `ShellExecute`. Of course, you have read the `ShellExecute` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) carefully, so you know what the return values are. So, you would easily have recognised `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and realised you need a fully-qualified path.

Comment: There isnt any ''file not found'' message. It just nothing happens. Also i cannot  have a full path bc ''C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXXXXX\My Game\bin\starter.exe'' the xxx is different for every PC. If i use the code i wrote in my question without the parameter -lang rus- The application starts normally even if i put the Launcher outside the ''bin'' folder with this comand: `ShellExecute(TForm(Owner).Handle, nil, 'bin\starter.exe', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: No, there is no message box. But I didn't say so, either. The 'return value' is the value **returned** by the function. Also, I did address the issue of finding the absolute path. I think you should pass an absolut path constructed at run-time. Anyhow, what *is* the return value? The last part of your comment suggests the issue is very specific to `starter.exe` (and so inappropriate for StackOverflow).

Comment: @user3211668 You are not checking for errors so what did you expect?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Actually, `ShellExecute` is basically useless when it comes to reporting errors. You need `ShellExecuteEx`.

Comment: @David: I see. But surely it will return `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` if it cannot find the file?

Comment: I guess i will embed the starter.exe inside the launcher, extract it inside the bin folder and then launch it.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes. But you have to hand code special error handling all for this one lame function. Which can only report certain errors. So, use `ShellExecuteEx` and `Win32Check`.

Comment: @user3211668 That's a bad idea. It is trivially easy to launch your process. Why would you give up so easily?