# Error when I run the easy-php devserver "run-devserver.exe" with ShellExecute

Tags: delphi, shellexecute, easyphp-devserver

I use easy-php devserver 17 on Windows 10 x64 without any problem if I click with the mouse on the "run-devserver.exe" file.

But in my new project, I want to run easy-php from my Delphi program (RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin).

I use this code:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'runas', 'c:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\run-devserver.exe', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I get this error (I think it created with MadExcept 3.0):

> Aestan Try menu: An error has occurred in Aestan Try Menu.

This error gives me some options, like the bug report, restart the application, close application!

I used some tips in another post like these:

[WAMP Server V 2.5 icon is orange,does not respond and no menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938739/)

[ShellExecute Command doesn't work properly in win10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046977/)

but they didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I guess you must start as administrator?, the problem is that your application starts without elevated privileges.Does it work when you start your application as administrator (ie right-click, select "run as administrator")?

Comment: yes, I start it as administrator but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Entirely possible that the difference is the working directory. As an aside, never call `ShellExecute` since it can't report errors properly. Use `ShellExecuteEx`.

Comment: I used "ShellExecuteEx" but the problem not solved. I even used the recommended methods of this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249995/delphi-7-shellexecute-command-not-working-in-situations

Comment: Please attention that error is for Dev-server 17, it means that the program is running good and I think "ShellExecute" or  "ShellExecuteEx" works without any problem, but maybe I need new configuration to run dev-server with another program or set some permission inside of configuration file, but which file !!?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. when I use this code the Error appears: "The directory name is invalid".

```
procedure TForm1.Button90Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName, Parameters, Folder: string;
  sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
  Error: DWORD;
  OK: boolean;
begin
   FileName := 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\run-devserver.exe';
   Parameters := '-lang rus';
   ZeroMemory(@sei, SizeOf(sei));
   sei.cbSize := SizeOf(sei);
   sei.lpFile := PChar(FileName);
   sei.lpParameters := PChar(Parameters);
   sei.lpDirectory := PChar(Folder);
   sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
   OK := ShellExecuteEx(@sei);
   if not OK then
   begin
      Error := GetLastError;
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + IntToStr(Error));
   end;
```

but when I edit folder and filename string like this code everything is OK.

```
Folder := 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\';
FileName := Folder + 'run-devserver.exe';
```